# MVC RedirectToAction not hiding parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following action

```
public ActionResult TemplateBuilder(int id, int? processId) { }
```

And then I have the following

```
@Url.Action("TemplateBuilder","InspectionTemplate")/id/processId
```

The url then looks like: `InspectionTemplate/TemplateBuilder/1/2`

But if I use

```
return RedirectToAction("TemplateBuilder","InspectionTemplate", new { id=1, processId = 2});
```

Then I get the following result: `InspectionTemplate/TemplateBuilder/1?processId=2`

How can I fix that.

Here is my Routing

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "IDRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Login",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProcessRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{processId}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "InspectionTemplate",
                action = "TemplateBuilder",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                processId = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DateRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{year}/{month}/{day}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Inspection",
                action = "Assign",
                year = UrlParameter.Optional,
                month = UrlParameter.Optional,
                day = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );


    }
```

Comment: Remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional,` from the `ProcessRoute` (only the last parameter can be optional) and change it to `url: "InspectionTemplate/{action}/{id}/{processId}",` so its specific and move it to be the first route (the order is important)

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Nevermind, it worked forgot to move it to the top. Add as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Note I rolled back your edit so that the answer and comments make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 issues with your route definitions

1. Only the last parameter in a route definition can be marked with
   `UrlParameter.Optional`. If you were to provide only one, then the
   routing engine has no way of knowing which parameter should be bound
   so the value(s) would be added as query string parameters).
2. The main issue however is the order of the routes. The routing
   engines searches the definitions in the order they are declared and 
   stops as soon as it finds a matching one, and in your case the
   `IDRoute` will match so the routes need to be swapped.
3. That alone however may cause issues with other route definitions, so
   its best to make your route uniquely identifiable, for example by
   specifying the controller name in the route definition.

Your definitions should be

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ProcessRoute",
        url: "InspectionTemplate/{action}/{id}/{processId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "InspectionTemplate", action = "TemplateBuilder", processId = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DateRoute",
        url: "Inspection/{action}/{year}/{month}/{day}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Inspection", action = "Assign", } // assumes all parameters are required
    );

    // The default will only be match if the url does not start with '/InspectionTemplate/' or '/Inspection/'
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IDRoute",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```